# How can you be made blood kin by the orcs in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been to every orc stronghold and can't seem to find a way to become blood kin.  Their respect is not given freely.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blood-Kin), you must complete any of these quests/challenges:

- Retrieve a Daedra Heart for the Orc blacksmith Moth gro-Bagol in Understone  Keep in Markarth.
- Speak to the Orc miner Gat gro-Shargakh after completing the quest "Clear Kolskeggr Mine".
- Retrieve The Last Scabbard of Akrash for Ghorza gra-Bagol, the Orc blacksmith stationed at the blacksmith forge near The Hag's Cure in Markarth.
- Complete a series of fetch quests for Urag gro-Shub, an Orc mage and the librarian of The Arcanaeum at The College of Winterhold.
- Speak to the Orc miner Lash gra-Dushnikh after killing the Silver-Blood mercenaries at Karthwasten for Ainethach. He will be nearby.
- Kill a dragon near the gates of a stronghold.
- Talk to Durak after completing "A New Order", from the Dawnguard questline.
- After reaching level 10 and reaching Largashbur, you should find Orcs fighting a giant. Help them and you will get a questline and entrance for Largashbur. Complete the questline and you will be considered Blood-Kin.

Alternatively, being an Orc also gains you entrance into the strongholds.

Comment: Not true in the last point. I'm an orc, and was not allowed in to any strongholds. I had to sneak in and steal the full set of orc armor I was after xD of course then again I'm a level 3 orc

Comment: Also, the quest [The Forgemaster's Fingers](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Forgemaster%27s_Fingers)